# How to get `<th>` instead of `<td>`?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tags

I want to have first element of my row as `<th>` I am doing this but I am getting `<td>` as my first element. What I am doing wrong?

Basically I want something like this `<tr><th><b>Table Header</b></th><td>item1</td><td>item2</td><\tr>`

```js
var table = document.getElementById("data");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    $("#table td:first").append('<th><b>Table Header</b></th>');
```

Comment: [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) will always/*only* create `td` - answer: don't use insertCell

Comment: Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14146139/2422776

Comment: also: $("td").append("th") won't give you valid html, maybe you wanted `.insertBefore`?

Comment: Just use jquery for adding all your html: `$("table#data").prepend("<tr><th>Table Header</th></tr>")`

Comment: what do i use in place of insertcell then?

Comment: @MisterJojo it would create <thead> tag, I dont want that

Answer (score 2):

You just need to not use insertCell in your question

```js
var table = document.getElementById("data");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
$(row).append('<th>Table Header</th>');
```

```html
<table id="data"></table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own method to insert a `<th>`

```js
// insert <TH> method, at  your oxn risk
HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.insert_th_Cell = function(index) 
  {
  let cell = this.insertCell(index)
    , c_th = document.createElement('th')
  cell.replaceWith(c_th)
  return c_th 
  }
//---------------------------------------

let thead   = myTable.createTHead()
  , tBody   = myTable.createTBody()
  , rowHead = thead.insertRow()
  ;
rowHead.insertCell()
rowHead.insert_th_Cell().textContent = 'c1'
rowHead.insert_th_Cell().textContent = 'c2'
rowHead.insert_th_Cell().textContent = 'c3'

 
let nRow = tBody.insertRow()
nRow.insert_th_Cell().textContent = 'line'
nRow.insertCell().textContent = 'AA'
nRow.insertCell().textContent = 'BB'
nRow.insertCell().textContent = 'CC'
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
tbody th{ 
  background-color: orchid;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```